# PhraseMatcher for matching phrases with words in between

Tags: spacy

Suppose I have the following two sentences: `"Onions are being cut. However, a great big cut to the onions have been observed"`, and I wish to match the phrase "Cutting onions". This is just a minimal example.

My requirement is that the algorithm goes through all sentences and returns a bool of whether the sentence contains that phrase or not. Also I only wish to match on the lemmatised version and it's ok to have 0 or more words between the phrases. Therefore in the example above, I expect it to return `[False, True]`. How would I go about doing this?

My half attempt is as follows (the places where I need helped is marked `TODO`):

```py
import spacy 
from spacy.matcher import PhraseMatcher 

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm') 
matcher = PhraseMatcher(nlp.vocab)

corpus = "onions are being cut. However, a great big cut to the onions have been observed"
pattern = "Cutting onions"
doc = nlp(corpus)
# TODO: how do I change the pattern to lemmatize and include any # of words between
matcher.add('pat1', None, pattern) 

results = []
for s in doc.sents:
    # TODO: can I use sentences as a doc?
    matches = matcher(s)
    if len(matches) > 0:
        results.append(True)
    else:
        results.append(False)
```

Comment: You are using `from spacy.matcher import PhraseMatcher`, but it seems  you want `from spacy.matcher import Matcher`.  Then, what is the point of the second `TODO`? Why collect True or False? What is the final result you need to obtain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using `spacy.matcher.Matcher` and get the matched sentence(s) after getting each match.

See a sample demo:

```
import spacy 
from spacy.matcher import Matcher
​
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm') 
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)
​
corpus = "onions are being cut. However, a great big cut to the onions have been observed"
doc = nlp(corpus)
pattern = [{'LEMMA': 'cut'},
           {'IS_ALPHA': True, 'OP': '*'},
           {'LEMMA': 'onion'}]
matcher.add('pat', None, pattern) 
​
matches = matcher(doc)
for match_id, start, end in matches:
    string_id = nlp.vocab.strings[match_id]  # Get string representation
    span = doc[start:end]  # The matched span
    print("Match ID: {}\nString ID: {}\nStart: {}\nEnd: {}\nText: {}\nSentence: {}".format(
      match_id, string_id, start, end, span.text, span.sent))
```

Output:

```
Match ID: 5387953638794962156
String ID: pat
Start: 10
End: 14
Text: cut to the onions
Sentence: However, a great big cut to the onions have been observed
```

Note the `pattern = [{'LEMMA': 'cut'},{'IS_ALPHA': True, 'OP': '*'},{'LEMMA': 'onion'}]` pattern matches a string that starts with `cut` lemma word (`{'LEMMA': 'cut'}`), then contains any 0 or more occurrences of any letter words (`{'IS_ALPHA': True, 'OP': '*'}`) and then has an `onion` lemma word.

Comment: can we add pattern in PharseMatcher class?

Comment: @GauravKoradiya See [here](https://spacy.io/api/phrasematcher): *The PhraseMatcher lets you efficiently match large terminology lists. While the Matcher lets you match sequences based on lists of token descriptions, the PhraseMatcher accepts match patterns in the form of Doc objects.* See [example here](https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching#phrasematcher).

Comment: Good. But i need to add pattern like /d+(-/d)* using PhraseMatcher class. I can see if its matter to match direct phrase then i agree with you. Can u recemmond any solution  if u have any?